# how to get the images changing by sliding the range slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am replicating this web page https://www.modsy.com/project/furniture I wrote the code but i am not getting the text in the row format as shown in the above web page

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");
          var output = document.getElementById("sliderOutput");
          var images = document.getElementById("sliderImages");
          rangeslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < output.children.length; i++) {
              output.children[i].style.display = 'none';
              images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            i = Number(this.value) - 1;
            output.children[i].style.display = 'block';
            images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
          });
        });
```

```css
      .rangeslider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #FCF3CF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.myslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #34495E;
  width: 33%;
  height: 20px;
}

.myslider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image>img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.image>img.visible,
.image>img:first-child {
  display: block;
}

#sliderOutput>div {
  display: none;
}

#sliderOutput>div.visible,
#sliderOutput>div:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="image mt-3 mb-3" id="sliderImages">
  <img src="../static/images/1.jpg" width="400" height="180">
  <img src="../static/images/2.jpg" width="400" height="180">
  <img src="../static/images/3.jpg" width="400" height="180">
</div><br>
<div class="rangeslider">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="myslider" id="sliderRange">
  <div id="sliderOutput" >
    <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
      <p class="demo"> I'm designing the room </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
      <p class="demo">I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
      <p class="demo">I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

By this code I am getting the images changing on sliding but the text below the range slider as shown in the website is not getting can you people how to do this.

```html
<div class="image mt-3 mb-3" id="sliderImages">
  <img src="../static/images/1.jpg" width="400" height="180">
  <img src="../static/images/2.jpg" width="400" height="180">
  <img src="../static/images/3.jpg" width="400" height="180">
</div><br>
<div class="rangeslider">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="myslider" id="sliderRange">
  <div id="sliderOutput" >
    <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
      <p class="demo"> I'm designing the room </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
      <p class="demo">I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
      <p class="demo">I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </p>
</div>    

<style>
        .rangeslider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #FCF3CF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.myslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #34495E;
  width: 33%;
  height: 20px;
}

.myslider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image>img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.image>img.visible,
.image>img:first-child {
  display: block;
}

#sliderOutput>div {
  display: none;
}

#sliderOutput>div.visible,
#sliderOutput>div:first-child {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<script> 
          window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");
          var output = document.getElementById("sliderOutput");
          var images = document.getElementById("sliderImages");
          rangeslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < output.children.length; i++) {
              output.children[i].style.display = 'none';
              images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            i = Number(this.value) - 1;
            output.children[i].style.display = 'block';
            images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
          });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: could you add a minimal code snippet for your particular issue, then I'll look into it.

Comment: @ phanti as i am new to stackoverflow I dont know how to do add snippets can you please guide me

Comment: use the `<>` symbol within the post editor, also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the button is right next to the insert image option

Comment: Yes thankyou @ Wali Waqar

Comment: @ phanti now can you see it and thankyou

Comment: did you close all your <div> tags, i see one less closing tag

Comment: Yes I had closed in my code but I am not getting like this webpage https://www.modsy.com/project/furniture can you please help

Comment: please clarify this. Your problem is that you want the text to change according to the slider position like 'starting from scratch' in first phase, 'somewhere in between' in the second, but they are all appearing together, right?

Comment: Yes To get the three phases in a row format and on sliding the images only should change

Comment: what do you mean by row format?

Comment: @ Wali row means side by side the phrases should come My actual requirement is to get the web page like this https://www.modsy.com/project/furniture and I should store the phrase in the local storage which the user has dragged either 1 0r 2 0r 3

Comment: can I do like that is my requirement poosible

Comment: @ phanti and @ wali can you please help

Comment: I don't know much about local storage, since i usually use localeforage, which a javascript api by mozilla, and uses indexedDB. You can find more about it at https://localforage.github.io/localForage/

Comment: Ok @ Wali can you say the styling how can I get as in the webpage which I specified what wrong with my code

Comment: you can use the "position" property of css (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), to position each text differently as you like

Comment: @ Wali like that only I had used the bootstrap grid system in my code even though I am not getting can you help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204978/discussion-between-madhavi-and-wali-waqar).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is one, not 3 children of `#sliderOutput`, i.e,        `<div class="row mt-3">`, and all the three sections of text are its children, not children of `#sliderOutput`, so when you change the display of the first child, all the text either appears or disappears.

You should either change your output variable to refer to `<div class="row mt-3">`, or remove this div, both of which would make the divs containing the text, direct children of the div to which *output* refers to in your javascript.

I guess this is the desired result

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");
  var output = document.getElementById("sliderOutput");
  var images = document.getElementById("sliderImages");
  rangeslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < output.children.length; i++) {
      output.children[i].style.display = 'none';
      images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    i = Number(this.value) - 1;
    output.children[i].style.display = 'block';
    images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
.rangeslider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #FCF3CF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.myslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #34495E;
  width: 33%;
  height: 20px;
}

.col-4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.myslider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image>img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.image>img.visible,
.image>img:first-child {
  display: block;
}

#sliderOutput>div {
  display: none;
}

#sliderOutput>div.visible,
#sliderOutput>div:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image mt-3 mb-3" id="sliderImages">
  <img src="../static/images/1.jpg" width="400" height="180">
  <img src="../static/images/2.jpg" width="400" height="180">
  <img src="../static/images/3.jpg" width="400" height="180">
</div><br>
<div class="rangeslider">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="myslider" id="sliderRange">
  <div id="sliderOutput">
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
      <p class="demo"> I'm designing the room </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
      <p class="demo">I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
      <p class="demo">I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Wali I am not getting as in the row format which i had specified in the problem description

Comment: @ Wali I am not getting the output as I desired with your code can you help